# Rosbag Python API: why do messages from a rosbag have mangled __class__?

Tags: python, rosbag, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find that messages loaded from a rosbag via the Python API, have a weird **class** attribute:

```
import rosbag
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

# Round-trip a PointCloud2 message to a rosbag and back
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w')
try:
    scan = PointCloud2()
    print("__class__should be: \n{}".format(scan.__class__))
    bag.write('scan', msg)
finally:
    bag.close()

bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['scan']):
    print("But it comes out as: \n{}".format(msg.__class__))
bag.close()
```

The output:

```
__class__should be: 
<class 'sensor_msgs.msg._PointCloud2.PointCloud2'>
But it comes out as: 
<class 'tmpf1u1_e._sensor_msgs__PointCloud2'>
```

Is this a bug, or a feature?

ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14, Python 2.7

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283698/rosbag-python-api:-why-do-messages-from-a-rosbag-have-mangled-__class__?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2018-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a feature, not a bug.

Instead of using or relying on the local message definitions, which may not match the message definitions stored in the bag file (or may not exist at all!), the python API for rosbag generates class definitions on the fly for each message type stored in the bag file. Unfortunately, these auto-generated classes don't have the same names as the original classes.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2